# Splitting text, by every nth character, in a specific column in text file, test for equivalency within new columns

Tags: split, text-manipulation

I'm trying to split a column in a text file and create new columns that contain every pair of characters. I eventually want to ask if the two characters match, and if so, replace the two with the shared character.  If they don't, then replace them with a '.' .

Current file:

```
206  GGGGGCGGCCNNGG
271  AAGTGANNGAGATT
```

Intermediate:

```
206  GG GG GC GG CC NN GG
271  AA GT GA NN GA GA TT
```

Desired output:

```
206  G G . G C N G
271  A . . N . . T
```

Comment: I would be happy just getting to the intermediate part. I think I might be able to figure out the last half on my own.

Comment: Which programming language are you using?